# How to change internal configuration of IIS by web.config?

Tags: iis-7, deployment

I want to change the authentication mode of a web service project on IIS to only basic authentication ...
i use VS 2010 and webDeploy for send my WCF (data service) project, in my web.config i have :

```
    <location path="Default Web Site/AdcamApi" allowOverride="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <!-- <add name="AuthenticationModule" type="AdcamApi.AuthenticationModule"/> -->
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

i see in log of webdeploy : "update setAcl" so i supose it's good, but when i return to the manager the authentication are the same :

- anomynous : enable
- basic : disable

i have tested lot of thing : allowOverride, different location etc. but without success.

note :

- When i change directly this mode in the IIS manager, the web.config of my directory is unchanged !
- the IIS and project not are in the same machine.(webdeploy by internet)

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager, select your server on the left. At the bottom in the Management section there is a 'Feature Delegation' icon, open it.

To be able to overwrite configuration in your web.config file, you need to set the delegation to 'Read/Write' for all the features that you want to change.